# Child component not emitting value to parent component's function

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have defined a function called `login` inside my parent component:

```
login(user: any) {
  console.log(user);
}
```

Then I have a login form component:

```
export class LoginFormComponent {
  @Output() onLogin: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.user = {};
  }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
<login-form (onLogin)="login(user)"></login-form>
```

Which looks something like this:

```
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
```

And inside this component I have a simple button which should execute the `onLogin` function and pass the user from `login-form` component to the outer component:

```
<button (click)="onLogin.emit(user)">Login</button>
```

The problem is that `user` is always undefined in the `login` function.

Why isn't `user` getting sent from `login-form` to my parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special identifier `$event` needs to be used to get the emitted value passed:

```
<login-form (onLogin)="login($event)"></login-form>
```

`user` refers to the `user` property of the component class.

Comment: That's just dumb, why is this? Mmmh, I figured that it was refering to the parent component but didn't think it worked like this.

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure why you think it is dumb. You can refer to any value of your component or to template variables. To make it clear to Angular that you want to pass the event value instead some other reference Angular has the `$event` identifier.

Comment: True, I guess it's pretty smart.. Will accept in time, cheerios :)